# PHP CURL and POSTMAN response for API call returns "district Id is required" even though I am passing it

Tags: php, api, curl, collections, postman

I am trying to call an API on this URL where I am expecting to insert a data. The API keeps returning "district id is required" even though I am passing the parameters completely. I am stuck since 3 days. Please refer to the screenshot below:

Postman Screenshot

[image]

API link I am calling here: https://hrtaskapi.dhwaniris.in/index.php/api/beneficiary/child-profile-create

Collection link: https://www.postman.com/collections/66c45e6146e3d7cbe41b

Required Header: API Key

```
parameter: token
value: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.ak3OSYopsW211SvJnzH4nNLvcj9Z4B16fR329fZbHeA
```

This problem persists when I try doing this with PHP CURL too using "PUT" or "POST" method.

PHP CURL Code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "district_id=1");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://hrtaskapi.dhwaniris.in/index.php/api/beneficiary/child-profile-create");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.jDfocuaZhPcTyefEm-ZH-VOdPEsUdc-r8-bdAW-MJwI',
  'Content-Type: application/json',
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($result));
```

CURL response:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [success] => 
  [status] => 200
  [message] => district Id is required
)
```

When I call this API Link https://hrtaskapi.dhwaniris.in/index.php/api/beneficiary/get-child-profile using CURL in PHP I get the following response:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [success] => 1
  [status] => 200
  [message] => Child Profile Detail
  [timestamp] => 1614518328
  [child_profile] => Array
    (
      [0] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 51
          [name] => Laxmi
          [sex] => 2
          [dob] => 2014-04-02
          [father_name] => Kishansingh
          [mother_name] => Uddi
          [district_id] => 1
          [photo] => https://staging-dhwani.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/82ac44b1c5d7ef91a9e912abca5fc3f5.jpg
        )

      [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 52
          [name] => Laxmi
          [sex] => 2
          [dob] => 2012-11-07
          [father_name] => Vinod nath
          [mother_name] => Babli bai
          [district_id] => 1
          [photo] => https://staging-dhwani.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/82ac44b1c5d7ef91a9e912abca5fc3f5.jpg
        )
    )
)
```

Above is the `district_id` that is required. If it will accept the district id then a new record will be created.

Comment: Do you have control over that API? Is there documentation somewhere? Might be there's an error the maintainer is not aware of, have you contacted them?

Comment: @brombeer yes I did. Actually I need to complete this task to get hired by the company. I literally made a video stating that it's not working and asked them to check the API on their end. They responded with a call stating that the API was working for them and I should not use FORM to submit instead I used use ROWS. Now that confused me. I said I got it and hung up. If I had asked them what they meant by ROWS here then there was a chance of rejection as it would have created an impression that I lack experience. Which was not true. But this ROWS thing? I heard first time.